# update 3rd party's .config transformation's from installer

Tags: c#, .net, xslt, config, transformation

I have 2 .config files that have to be configured. One is a `web.config` and one is an `app.config`, both of these files are from a 3rd party vendor that our code runs inside.  So we need to make adjustments to it so it sees our code.

My plan was to use xslt to take our .config file and merge it into the 3rd party one.

I've seen a few examples on how to do this type of thing with msbuild, but since we are doing it on site, we are going to have to do it with an installer. Any help would be appreciated.

Example:
We are starting out with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <gcServer enabled="true"/>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Custom Section

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="productName" type="company.productName, company, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d9072a6c5128d57c" />
  </configSections>
  <productName defaultProvider="Provider1">
    <providers>
      <clear />
      <add name="Provider1" type="Company.Product.Authentication.Provider1, Company.Product, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d9072a6c5128d57c" hostName="localhost:5555" />
      <add name="Provider2" type="Company.Product.Authentication.Provider2, Company.Product, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d9072a6c5128d57c" hostName="demo.example.com" />
    </providers>
  </productName>
</configuration>
```

And ending with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="productName" type="company.productName, company, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d9072a6c5128d57c" />
  </configSections>
  <productName defaultProvider="Provider1">
    <providers>
      <clear />
      <add name="Provider1" type="Company.Product.Authentication.Provider1, Company.Product, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d9072a6c5128d57c" hostName="localhost:5555" />
      <add name="Provider2" type="Company.Product.Authentication.Provider2, Company.Product, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d9072a6c5128d57c" hostName="demo.example.com" />
    </providers>
  </productName>
  <runtime>
    <gcServer enabled="true"/>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Would the transformation be just to copy one `configuration`'s children into another?

Comment: @Alejandro: That is correct, to check if it is there, if not add it. If it is then leave it alone.

Comment: That's not what I wrote. You need to clarify what are the meaning of `check if it is there` and `leave it alone`.

Comment: @Alejandro: Thanks for the tips, I really don't work with XML much, but from a SQL point of view, it would check if the element exists, if so update it in case it changed. Or if it did exist an insert would take place and add the new element in the correct location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="document('test.xml')/*">
            <xsl:with-param name="pContext" select="*"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[*]">
        <xsl:param name="pContext" select="/.."/>
        <xsl:variable name="vCurrent" select="."/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$pContext/@*"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="*">
                <xsl:apply-templates select=".">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pContext"
                         select="$pContext/*[name()=name(current())]"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:for-each select="$pContext/*">
                <xsl:apply-templates
                     select="(.)[not($vCurrent/*[name()=name(current())])]"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[not(*)]">
        <xsl:param name="pContext" select="/.."/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$pContext/@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates
                 select="node()[not($pContext)]|$pContext/node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

With this input:

```
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <gcServer enabled="true"/>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

And this `test.xml`:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="productName" type="company.productName, company, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d9072a6c5128d57c" />
    </configSections>
    <productName defaultProvider="Provider1">
        <providers>
            <clear />
            <add name="Provider1" type="Company.Product.Authentication.Provider1, Company.Product, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d9072a6c5128d57c" hostName="localhost:5555" />
            <add name="Provider2" type="Company.Product.Authentication.Provider2, Company.Product, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d9072a6c5128d57c" hostName="demo.example.com" />
        </providers>
    </productName>
</configuration>
```

Output:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="productName" type="company.productName, company, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d9072a6c5128d57c"></section>
    </configSections>
    <productName defaultProvider="Provider1">
        <providers>
            <clear></clear>
            <add name="Provider1" type="Company.Product.Authentication.Provider1, Company.Product, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d9072a6c5128d57c" hostName="localhost:5555"></add>
            <add name="Provider2" type="Company.Product.Authentication.Provider2, Company.Product, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d9072a6c5128d57c" hostName="demo.example.com"></add>
        </providers>
    </productName>
    <runtime>
        <gcServer enabled="true"></gcServer>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

**Note**: Three rules. Document root rule: change the traversing tree to a source needing update and keep input source as `$pContext`. Element with elements children rule: copy itself with attributes, update attributes with `$pContext`'s attributes (this is done by the processor because [creating attributes rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#creating-attributes)), apply templates to elements children with new `$pContext` (a child of old `$pContext` with the same name), apply templates to `$pContext`'s children wich don't match any children's names. Element without elements children rule: copy itself with attributes updated with `$pContext` attributes, if there is a node in `$pContext` copy it, thus replacing element content (or even stripping if you have an empty element in `$pContext`).

Comment: worked great, if you could explain a little how it works that would be super!

Comment: @Matt Heffernan: You are welcome! I will come back and add an explanation.

Comment: @Matt Heffernan: Explanation added.